# Monaca Cloud is not accessible through Angular

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I have a Monaca app with ONSEN UI . it is build with angularJS.
I am trying to access the Monaca cloud using angular in my app. 
My index.html looks like. I incuded the monaca-cloud-angular.js
as described in document 
http://monaca.mobi/en/blog/lets-make-an-angularjs-module-for-monaca-backend/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesshet" href="components/monaca-onsenui/js/angular/angular-csp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"> </script>
    <script src="js/monaca-cloud-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="QubecNavigator" page="welcome.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

Welcome page has a welcomecontroller. and in angular i defined like this.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen','angularRandomString','monaca.cloud']);
  app.controller('welcomeController',function($scope,$http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike,MonacaBackend){
    ons.ready(function() {
      // Add another Onsen UI element
      console.log('I am here in Welcome');
      MonacaBackend.User.register('12345678','admin').then(
        function(result){
          console.log(result);
          $scope.result = result;
        },
        function(error){
          console.log(error);
        }
      );  
    });  
  });
};
```

I am not able to get any response from Monaca backend and user records are not registering in it.

Comment: is there any error message displayed?

Comment: There is no error message. It is just bypassing this statement. I tried to put message before and after the MonacaBackend statement.

Comment: It's a little bit weird, if you don't get `result` you should at least get `error`

Comment: I will try that once again today....